# Can I add software engineering to my resume if I do not have a software engineering degree specifically?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, resume

So I have an aerospace electrical engineering degree. 
I am currently doing my masters in data science.
For many years I have also had an avid passion for software engineering but I did not attain a software engineering degree.

In my resume I want to have three tags that relate to my focused areas of skill as follows:

**Data Science - Aerospace Electrical Engineering - Software Engineering**

Any advice will greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As someone who has read many resumes, I'd advise against things like tags. Include those words in a description of your degrees and the courses you took.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on how to write a resume. You can't just throw random bits and pieces in there. There is a certain format that most companies will look for, but it will depend on your locale. The format will allow you to put hobbies and interests in there.

Comment: Also illegal in some jurisdiction, like Quebec, Canada, where you need to be a member of a professional order

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: "Interests and hobbies" and "Skills" are two very different sections. If the OP has acquired skills in software development, then it is a valid skill regardless of how it was obtained.

Comment: @Flater That may be so, but he says he has "an avid passion" which sounds more like a hobby than a developed skill.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: There's a difference between "an avid passion" and "an avid passion _but not a degree_". The latter implies that "passion" is meant to quantify the level of certification as opposed to skill. Regardless, an avid passion by itself still wouldn't preclude an actual acquired skill.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, I have university core subjects in software development/techniques and the level is significantly advanced - its more than a hobby, as *Flater* pointed out.  The answers on this thread is much appreciated and I've gained a better understanding with the legal aspects - Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some countries, the title "Engineer" is protected by law, you must have obtained the corresponding degree.

I would advise you to label your expertise as:

> Data Science - Aerospace Electrical Engineering - Software **development**

This would leave the possible issue aside and the result would almost be the same.

Comment: I think your suggestion is perfect for what I'm trying to convey, thanks a tonne

Comment: +1 for pointing out the law protected status... I'm unsure the software development qualifies as expertise though

Answer (score 3):

Best advice: do not lie on your cv.

If software was a part of your degree you can mention it.

If you studied it on your own then mention it as private interests or hobbies but do not claim it as part of a qualification if it was not part of that qualification.

Comment: That is great advice - My degree did have a lot of software/programming aspects so I am not sure how (or how to find out) how my degree equates with other fields of engineering.